# Center background image with header

Tags: css

I have a JSFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/ow1x3e0a/14/

Simple CSS problem.

I have a header which I need to have an image on the side of. I can do this with a background image.

When the window is smaller I need to center the text and image so it appears in the center as it does on the left.

At the moment the text centers but the image stays on the left

I have tried it with without text-align but can't center it with `margin: auto:`

```
.container{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.header{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 110px;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x50);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
  .header{
      text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding ` background-position:` ?

Comment: center center doesn't work  jsfiddle.net/ow1x3e0a/30 – ttmt 1 min ago   edit

Comment: try `background-position: 0% 0%;` Then play around with the numbers

Answer (score 1):

When you are giving the background, you need to use:

```
background-position: center center;
```

The `text-align: center` or `margin: auto` are only for contents, not background.

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-position: center center` (or shorthand `background: url(...) center center;`). Adjust padding to get it aligned how you want.

Comment: It works exactly as it should. Your padding-left is pushing your text causing the misalignment, hence "Adjust padding to get it aligned how you want." Remove the padding-left and you'll see it line up perfectly.
Padding will not push the background image along with the text.

Comment: Can you show me on the jsfiddle, i can't get it to work